# If $f(z)$ is continuous inside and on a simple closed contour $C$ and $\int_C f(z)dz=0,$ is $f(z)$ analytic inside $C?$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

> If $f(z)$ is continuous inside and on a simple closed contour $C$ and $\int_C f(z)dz=0,$ is $f(z)$ analytic inside $C?$

My Attempt: I've found a counterexample: Let $C:|z|=1$ and $f:z\mapsto |z|.$ Then $f$ is continuous inside and on $C.$ Also, $\int_C f(z)dz=\int_C|z|dz=\int_C dz=0$ [by Cauchy's Integral Formula]

But $f$ is not differentiable at $0.$

Am I right?

Comment: Question is not clear. Do you want to show $|z|$ is not analytic, by finding a closed curve on which $\int |z| \neq 0$ or the mistake in the top statement? I assume the second one. $f$ is not analytic can be easily shown by C-R equation.

Answer (score 2):

The statement is **not** true. There are many easy to find counterexamples. Take the example where $f(z)=Re(z)$ or $f(z)=\overline{z}$.

However, from the comments and answers let me say this. This may seem like a place for Morera's Theorem. While it does not need simple connectedness, Morera's Theorem says that if $f(z)$ is continuous in a region $D$ (such as the region bounded by your curve $C$) and satisfies $$\oint_C f(z) dz$$ for ALL closed contours $C$ in the region $D$ then $f(z)$ is analytic in $D$. Finding just one such that the integral is $0$ does not suffice.

Also, note that your integral is not zero. I suggest you parametrize and try the integral yourself and see that it does not come out to be $0$. You try to apply Cauchy's Integral Formula. However, this already assumes that your function $f(z)$ is analytic in your region bounded by $C$, which it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes; if C is defined in a simply-connected region ;this is the content of Morera's theorem.

EDIT: I assumed you meant for *all* closed contours, but after someone questioned, Irealized I'm not 100% sure of what you meant. Could you clarify?

You can check for differentiability relatively-easily here, since f(z) is Real-valued, Cauchy-Riemann greatly simplifies.

Moreover, if you integrate |z| over |z|=1, you can use polars to get the integral $|re^{i\theta}|=r$ from $0$ to $2\pi$, which is not $0$

Comment: Morera's Theorem says that it is analytic inside $C$ if $\int_C=0$ holds for ANY closed piecewise $C^1$ curve inside your region, not just one such $C$. Moreover, nowhere here did it say that $f(z)$ was real valued.

Comment: I assumed s/he meant for every contour $C$. I was also referring to f(z)=|z| being real-valued.

Comment: And that would make it an easy question to answer given Morera's Theorem. However, he does specifically say just a simple closed curve $C$ and counterexamples for the regularity of the function like the ones I gave are easy to come up with if you don't have that extra stipulation.

Comment: Well, let's let the OP explain what s/he meant; I'm not sure either way. Obviously the result does not hold if the integral is zero about just one contour.

Answer (score 0):

No; $f$ is continuous on a region $\Omega$ and if $\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz = 0$ for all closed curve $\gamma$ in $\Omega$ then $f$ is analytic in $\Omega$. $\int_{\gamma}f = 0$ on a single closed curve does not imply $f$ is analytic.

It is related to Morera's theorem. Theorem and proof is available at any standard text on complex analysis.

To prove $f = |z|$ is analytic inside the unit closed disk we require to show $\int_{\gamma}|z| dz = 0$ $\forall$ closed curve $\gamma$ inside the unite disk. It may be true for $\gamma : |z| = 1$ as you have calculated, but may not be hold for some other closed curve in the unite disk. Moreover $|z|$ is not analytic in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: The point is that you are showing that the statement is NOT true. He doesn't need that it holds for all curves. Merely, he need show that he can find a $f(z)$ that integrates to $0$ along his simple closed curve, where $f(z)$ is continuous and not have it be analytic. He need only find a curve where the integral is zero and find that it has a point in his region where it is not analytic. So the function is not analytic inside $C$. Then he is done.

Comment: I want to say that $\int_{C}f = 0$ for a single curve $C$ does not imply that $f$ is analytic, as she has done.

Comment: That's the whole point! She is trying to show that it is NOT analytic. She's finding a counterexample (though unsuccessfully). She's found a simple closed curve with a function that is continuous on it. Had the integral come out to $0$ because $f(z)=|z|$ is NOT analytic inside the curve $C$, the counterexample would have been found.

Comment: No she is doubted on Morer's theorem. Hope she has checked all of these; $|z|$ is not differentible at $z = 0$, Cauchy-Riemman equation all. But she could not match the Morar's theorem with them.

Comment: Again, you've missed it. This isn't Morera's Theorem. This is a separate problem talking about only a *single* simple closed curve $C$, not any or all such curves. In fact, this is very similar to many True/False questions you see in some textbooks. I can only assume it is that type of question or they have failed to state correctly that this is to hold for all simple closed $C$. Hence, the fact that $|z|$ is not analytic at $0$ is wanted so long as they can find a S.C.C around 0 that integrates to $0$. As then, they will have found their counterexample to the statements veracity.